FFmpeg Could not write header (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid data found when processing input
The command
ffmpeg -v verbose -i in.mkv -c copy -y out.mkv

produces the following error:
ffmpeg version 7.0.1-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2024 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 13.2.0 (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libaribcaption --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libxevd --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxeve --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libjxl --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libharfbuzz --enable-liblensfun --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-dxva2 --enable-d3d11va --enable-d3d12va --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-libvpl --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-vaapi --enable-libshaderc --enable-vulkan --enable-libplacebo --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      59.  8.100 / 59.  8.100
  libavcodec     61.  3.100 / 61.  3.100
  libavformat    61.  1.100 / 61.  1.100
  libavdevice    61.  1.100 / 61.  1.100
  libavfilter    10.  1.100 / 10.  1.100
  libswscale      8.  1.100 /  8.  1.100
  libswresample   5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libpostproc    58.  1.100 / 58.  1.100
[hevc @ 00000133b5bb5040] Invalid default display window
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'in.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : libebml v1.3.0 + libmatroska v1.4.1
    creation_time   : 2015-03-20T14:07:27.000000Z
  Duration: 00:24:11.75, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 5185 kb/s
  Chapters:
    Chapter #0:0: start 0.000000, end 48.047000
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 01
    Chapter #0:1: start 48.047000, end 137.846000
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 02
    Chapter #0:2: start 137.846000, end 535.868000
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 03
    Chapter #0:3: start 535.868000, end 1330.871000
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 04
    Chapter #0:4: start 1330.871000, end 1420.877000
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 05
    Chapter #0:5: start 1420.877000, end 1451.741000
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 06
    Chapter #0:6: start 1451.741000, end 1451.745000
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 07
  Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (Main 10), 1 reference frame, yuv420p10le(tv, left), 1920x1080, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn (default)
      Metadata:
        _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v7.0.0 ('Where We Going') 32bit built on Jun  9 2014 15:08:34
        _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v7.0.0 ('Where We Going') 32bit built on Jun  9 2014 15:08:34
        _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2015-03-20 14:07:27
        _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2015-03-20 14:07:27
        _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
        _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
        BPS             : 3754023
        BPS-eng         : 3754023
        DURATION        : 00:24:11.742000000
        DURATION-eng    : 00:24:11.742000000
        NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 34807
        NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 34807
        NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 681234123
        NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 681234123
  Stream #0:1(jpn): Audio: flac, 48000 Hz, stereo, s32 (24 bit) (default)
      Metadata:
        _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v7.0.0 ('Where We Going') 32bit built on Jun  9 2014 15:08:34
        _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v7.0.0 ('Where We Going') 32bit built on Jun  9 2014 15:08:34
        _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2015-03-20 14:07:27
        _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2015-03-20 14:07:27
        _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
        _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
        BPS             : 1429414
        BPS-eng         : 1429414
        DURATION        : 00:24:11.745000000
        DURATION-eng    : 00:24:11.745000000
        NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 17013
        NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 17013
        NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 259393130
        NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 259393130
[out#0/matroska @ 00000133b5bb5a40] No explicit maps, mapping streams automatically...
[vost#0:0/copy @ 00000133b5c2f580] Created video stream from input stream 0:0
[aost#0:1/copy @ 00000133b5bf1680] Created audio stream from input stream 0:1
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
[out#0/matroska @ 00000133b5bb5a40] Could not write header (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid data found when processing input
[AVIOContext @ 00000133b5c27940] Statistics: 291 bytes written, 0 seeks, 1 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 00000133b5b97980] Statistics: 66432 bytes read, 2 seeks
Conversion failed!

Originally, I was trying to add a subtitle to in.mkv, but I keep encountering this error. When I add the subtitle to another MKV file, it works fine, so I believe the problem lies with in.mkv.
Troubleshooting
Output only video stream produce the same error:
ffmpeg -i in.mkv -map 0:v:0 -c copy out.mkv

Output only audio stream works fine:
ffmpeg -i in.mkv -map 0:a:0 -c copy out.mkv

Output as mp4 got no error, but the output file is unplayable:
ffmpeg -i in.mkv -c copy -strict -2 out.mp4

Re-encoding works fine:
ffmpeg -i in.mkv -c:v libx265 -c:a copy out.mkv

Removing chapters or metadata still produce the same error:
ffmpeg -i in.mkv -map_chapters -1 -c copy out.mkv
ffmpeg -i in.mkv -map_metadata -1 -c copy out.mkv

Using mkvmerge works well, but why ffmpeg failed?
mkvmerge -o out.mkv in.mkv subtitle.ass

I have searched for this error, but it seems that the situations are all different from mine. Are there any other ways to get a more detailed error message?

Maybe some problem with the chapters try removing them with -map_chapters -1, if that doesn't work try removing all metadata: -map_metadata -1....

@RicardoBohner I tried both options, but I'm still getting the same error.

The input vídeo might be damaged at some point, try to repair it with somethinng like this: ffmpeg -err_detect ignore_err -i video.mkv -c copy video_fixed.mkv

@RicardoBohner Still producing the same error. Btw, I inspected the metadata and found that the file was processed by mkvmerge, so I tried mkvmerge -o out.mkv in.mkv subtitle.ass, and everything worked well. Althoung it solves my original problem, I'm still curious about why ffmpeg produced the error. Is there other method I can try to find out the problem?

Is it possible for you to provide the file?

@JayCravens Sure, here's the link

Thank you for providing the source.Without, it's very likely, I couldn't have done it.
Extract video:
ffmpeg -i in.mkv -c copy -an -tag:v hvc1 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.ts

Extract audio:
ffmpeg -i in.mkv -c copy -vn out.flac

Re-mux:
ffmpeg -i out.ts -i out.flac -c copy out.mkv

No re-encoding required!
The "Invalid default display window" message seems to be a known issue with ffmpeg and it's safe to ignore.

Since the "why of it" was the real interest in the question, here is the log of what I tried and how I figured it out.
fedora@/dev/pts/4:$ ffprobe VCB-Studio.mkv
[hevc @ 0x55fc4c4ac000] Invalid default display window
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'VCB-Studio.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : libebml v1.3.0 + libmatroska v1.4.1
    creation_time   : 2015-03-20T14:07:27.000000Z
  Duration: 00:24:11.75, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 5185 kb/s
  Chapters:
    Chapter #0:0: start 0.000000, end 48.047000
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 01
    Chapter #0:1: start 48.047000, end 137.846000
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 02
    Chapter #0:2: start 137.846000, end 535.868000
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 03
    Chapter #0:3: start 535.868000, end 1330.871000
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 04
    Chapter #0:4: start 1330.871000, end 1420.877000
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 05
    Chapter #0:5: start 1420.877000, end 1451.741000
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 06
    Chapter #0:6: start 1451.741000, end 1451.745000
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 07
  Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (Main 10), yuv420p10le(tv), 1920x1080, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v7.0.0 ('Where We Going') 32bit built on Jun  9 2014 15:08:34
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v7.0.0 ('Where We Going') 32bit built on Jun  9 2014 15:08:34
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2015-03-20 14:07:27
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2015-03-20 14:07:27
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      BPS             : 3754023
      BPS-eng         : 3754023
      DURATION        : 00:24:11.742000000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:24:11.742000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 34807
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 34807
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 681234123
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 681234123
  Stream #0:1(jpn): Audio: flac, 48000 Hz, stereo, s32 (24 bit) (default)
    Metadata:
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v7.0.0 ('Where We Going') 32bit built on Jun  9 2014 15:08:34
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v7.0.0 ('Where We Going') 32bit built on Jun  9 2014 15:08:34
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2015-03-20 14:07:27
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2015-03-20 14:07:27
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      BPS             : 1429414
      BPS-eng         : 1429414
      DURATION        : 00:24:11.745000000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:24:11.745000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 17013
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 17013
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 259393130
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 259393130
[hevc @ 0x55fc4c4d9840] Invalid default display window

Looked and found out that it was an ffmpeg bug, and shouldn't be any issue.


fedora@/dev/pts/4:$ ffmpeg -f hevc -i VCB-Studio.mkv -c copy -pix_fmt yuv420p out.ts
[hevc @ 0x55a66de94c80] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
    Last message repeated 7 times
[hevc @ 0x55a66de94c80] Invalid NAL unit 4, skipping.
[hevc @ 0x55a66de94c80] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
[hevc @ 0x55a66de94c80] Invalid NAL unit 1, skipping.
[hevc @ 0x55a66de94c80] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
    Last message repeated 2 times
[hevc @ 0x55a66de94c80] missing picture in access unit with size 11255478
[extract_extradata @ 0x55a66deb5740] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
    Last message repeated 7 times
[extract_extradata @ 0x55a66deb5740] Invalid NAL unit 4, skipping.
[extract_extradata @ 0x55a66deb5740] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
[extract_extradata @ 0x55a66deb5740] Invalid NAL unit 1, skipping.
[extract_extradata @ 0x55a66deb5740] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
    Last message repeated 2 times
[hevc @ 0x55a66de94c80] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
    Last message repeated 7 times
[hevc @ 0x55a66de94c80] Invalid NAL unit 4, skipping.
[hevc @ 0x55a66de94c80] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
[hevc @ 0x55a66de94c80] Invalid NAL unit 1, skipping.
[hevc @ 0x55a66de94c80] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
    Last message repeated 2 times
[hevc @ 0x55a66de8bd00] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
[hevc @ 0x55a66de8bd00] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: hevc, none): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (0) and 'probesize' (5000000) options
Input #0, hevc, from 'VCB-Studio.mkv':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #0:0: Video: hevc, none, 25 fps, 1200k tbr, 1200k tbn
Output #0, mpegts, to 'out.ts':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf60.16.100
  Stream #0:0: Video: hevc, none, q=2-31, 25 fps, 1200k tbr, 90k tbn
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[NULL @ 0x55a66de94c80] Invalid NAL unit 35, skipping.
[NULL @ 0x55a66de94c80] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
    Last message repeated 1 times
[NULL @ 0x55a66de94c80] Invalid NAL unit 34, skipping.
[NULL @ 0x55a66de94c80] Invalid NAL unit 38, skipping.
[NULL @ 0x55a66de94c80] missing picture in access unit with size 21988998
[out#0/mpegts @ 0x55a66deb57c0] video:0kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
[out#0/mpegts @ 0x55a66deb57c0] Output file is empty, nothing was encoded
size=       0kB time=N/A bitrate=N/A speed=N/A    
fedora@/dev/pts/4:$ 

I first tried to specify the format of the input file, -f hevc, but I didn't like that.

fedora@/dev/pts/4:$ ffmpeg -f hevc -i VCB-Studio.mkv -c copy -pix_fmt yuv420p10le -f webm out.webm
[hevc @ 0x55a00371acc0] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
    Last message repeated 7 times
[hevc @ 0x55a00371acc0] Invalid NAL unit 4, skipping.
[hevc @ 0x55a00371acc0] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
[hevc @ 0x55a00371acc0] Invalid NAL unit 1, skipping.
[hevc @ 0x55a00371acc0] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
    Last message repeated 2 times
[hevc @ 0x55a00371acc0] missing picture in access unit with size 11255478
[extract_extradata @ 0x55a0036efc00] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
    Last message repeated 7 times
[extract_extradata @ 0x55a0036efc00] Invalid NAL unit 4, skipping.
[extract_extradata @ 0x55a0036efc00] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
[extract_extradata @ 0x55a0036efc00] Invalid NAL unit 1, skipping.
[extract_extradata @ 0x55a0036efc00] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
    Last message repeated 2 times
[hevc @ 0x55a00371acc0] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
    Last message repeated 7 times
[hevc @ 0x55a00371acc0] Invalid NAL unit 4, skipping.
[hevc @ 0x55a00371acc0] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
[hevc @ 0x55a00371acc0] Invalid NAL unit 1, skipping.
[hevc @ 0x55a00371acc0] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
    Last message repeated 2 times
[hevc @ 0x55a003711e40] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
[hevc @ 0x55a003711e40] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: hevc, none): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (0) and 'probesize' (5000000) options
Input #0, hevc, from 'VCB-Studio.mkv':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #0:0: Video: hevc, none, 25 fps, 1200k tbr, 1200k tbn
[webm @ 0x55a00374c040] dimensions not set
[out#0/webm @ 0x55a00373b780] Could not write header (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error opening output file out.webm.
Error opening output files: Invalid argument

So I tried to see if I could force it through to .webm even using the orginal color space.  Nope.


fedora@/dev/pts/4:$ ffmpeg -f hevc -analyzeduration 1500 -i VCB-Studio.mkv -c copy -pix_fmt yuv420p -f webm out.webm
[hevc @ 0x55c43ef5f2c0] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
    Last message repeated 7 times
[hevc @ 0x55c43ef5f2c0] Invalid NAL unit 4, skipping.
[hevc @ 0x55c43ef5f2c0] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
[hevc @ 0x55c43ef5f2c0] Invalid NAL unit 1, skipping.
[hevc @ 0x55c43ef5f2c0] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
    Last message repeated 2 times
[hevc @ 0x55c43ef5f2c0] missing picture in access unit with size 11255478
[extract_extradata @ 0x55c43ef7e900] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
    Last message repeated 7 times
[extract_extradata @ 0x55c43ef7e900] Invalid NAL unit 4, skipping.
[extract_extradata @ 0x55c43ef7e900] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
[extract_extradata @ 0x55c43ef7e900] Invalid NAL unit 1, skipping.
[extract_extradata @ 0x55c43ef7e900] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
    Last message repeated 2 times
[hevc @ 0x55c43ef5f2c0] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
    Last message repeated 7 times
[hevc @ 0x55c43ef5f2c0] Invalid NAL unit 4, skipping.
[hevc @ 0x55c43ef5f2c0] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
[hevc @ 0x55c43ef5f2c0] Invalid NAL unit 1, skipping.
[hevc @ 0x55c43ef5f2c0] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
    Last message repeated 2 times
[hevc @ 0x55c43ef562c0] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
[hevc @ 0x55c43ef562c0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: hevc, none): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (1500) and 'probesize' (5000000) options
Input #0, hevc, from 'VCB-Studio.mkv':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #0:0: Video: hevc, none, 25 fps, 1200k tbr, 1200k tbn
File 'out.webm' already exists. Overwrite? [y/N] n   
Not overwriting - exiting
Error opening output file out.webm.

So I listened and tried to increase -analyzeduration, but no success.


I searched around for errors related to HEVC and found:
https://github.com/jellyfin/jellyfin/issues/8495#issuecomment-1927383860

I ran this:

fedora@/dev/pts/4:$ ffmpeg -i VCB-Studio.mkv -c copy -tag:v hvc1 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.ts
[hevc @ 0x56067c738840] Invalid default display window
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'VCB-Studio.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : libebml v1.3.0 + libmatroska v1.4.1
    creation_time   : 2015-03-20T14:07:27.000000Z
  Duration: 00:24:11.75, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 5185 kb/s
  Chapters:
    Chapter #0:0: start 0.000000, end 48.047000
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 01
    Chapter #0:1: start 48.047000, end 137.846000
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 02
    Chapter #0:2: start 137.846000, end 535.868000
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 03
    Chapter #0:3: start 535.868000, end 1330.871000
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 04
    Chapter #0:4: start 1330.871000, end 1420.877000
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 05
    Chapter #0:5: start 1420.877000, end 1451.741000
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 06
    Chapter #0:6: start 1451.741000, end 1451.745000
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 07
  Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (Main 10), yuv420p10le(tv), 1920x1080, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v7.0.0 ('Where We Going') 32bit built on Jun  9 2014 15:08:34
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v7.0.0 ('Where We Going') 32bit built on Jun  9 2014 15:08:34
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2015-03-20 14:07:27
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2015-03-20 14:07:27
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      BPS             : 3754023
      BPS-eng         : 3754023
      DURATION        : 00:24:11.742000000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:24:11.742000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 34807
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 34807
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 681234123
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 681234123
  Stream #0:1(jpn): Audio: flac, 48000 Hz, stereo, s32 (24 bit) (default)
    Metadata:
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v7.0.0 ('Where We Going') 32bit built on Jun  9 2014 15:08:34
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v7.0.0 ('Where We Going') 32bit built on Jun  9 2014 15:08:34
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2015-03-20 14:07:27
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2015-03-20 14:07:27
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      BPS             : 1429414
      BPS-eng         : 1429414
      DURATION        : 00:24:11.745000000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:24:11.745000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 17013
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 17013
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 259393130
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 259393130
Output #0, mpegts, to 'out.ts':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf60.16.100
  Chapters:
    Chapter #0:0: start 0.000000, end 48.047000
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 01
    Chapter #0:1: start 48.047000, end 137.846000
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 02
    Chapter #0:2: start 137.846000, end 535.868000
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 03
    Chapter #0:3: start 535.868000, end 1330.871000
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 04
    Chapter #0:4: start 1330.871000, end 1420.877000
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 05
    Chapter #0:5: start 1420.877000, end 1451.741000
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 06
    Chapter #0:6: start 1451.741000, end 1451.745000
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 07
  Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (Main 10) (hvc1 / 0x31637668), yuv420p10le(tv), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 90k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v7.0.0 ('Where We Going') 32bit built on Jun  9 2014 15:08:34
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v7.0.0 ('Where We Going') 32bit built on Jun  9 2014 15:08:34
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2015-03-20 14:07:27
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2015-03-20 14:07:27
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      BPS             : 3754023
      BPS-eng         : 3754023
      DURATION        : 00:24:11.742000000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:24:11.742000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 34807
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 34807
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 681234123
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 681234123
  Stream #0:1(jpn): Audio: flac, 48000 Hz, stereo, s32 (24 bit) (default)
    Metadata:
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v7.0.0 ('Where We Going') 32bit built on Jun  9 2014 15:08:34
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v7.0.0 ('Where We Going') 32bit built on Jun  9 2014 15:08:34
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2015-03-20 14:07:27
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2015-03-20 14:07:27
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      BPS             : 1429414
      BPS-eng         : 1429414
      DURATION        : 00:24:11.745000000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:24:11.745000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 17013
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 17013
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 259393130
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 259393130
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mpegts @ 0x56067c766c80] Stream 1, codec flac, is muxed as a private data stream and may not be recognized upon reading.
[out#0/mpegts @ 0x56067c73d000] video:665268kB audio:253314kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 3.366844%
size=  949509kB time=00:24:11.69 bitrate=5358.2kbits/s speed= 875x    

and it worked, but the audio was not playing, despite being there, it was "private".  The video worked great though, so I just seperated the .ts and the .flac, remuxed and it was a success!

